# Apache Beam / Google dataflow - Error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline with quite a few steps (just above 15). I want to report failures everytime a `DoFn` fails. I started implementing it through `TupleTags` with code such as :

```
try {
 ... do stuff ...
 c.output(successTag, ...);
} catch (Exception e) {
 c.output(failureTag, new Failure(...));
}
```

But since my pipeline contains a lot of steps, this make the pipeline definition code quite hard to read / maintain.

Is there a more global way to achieve it ? Something like raising a custom exception which is handled globally at the pipeline level ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is the correct approach to catch errors and output them differently. You will need this on each step though. You could use a java pattern to reuse it if you prefer. Create a base class for all your ParDos and in processElement add the exception handling code. Then implement your processElement in a separate function (i.e. processElementImpl) which you call in processElement.

Comment: Thanks @alex. I'm not too worried about the exception handling itself in the DoFn as this is only a few lines. I'm more concerned about the plumbing in the pipeline. You think I'm out of options ?

Comment: Yes, I think that you will need to catch all Exceptions in every step of your pipeline. I recommend using a design pattern to reuse the block of code.

See the mobile gaming pipeline. Create a named class instead of an anonymous class for the DoFn, imp. element your exception handling logic in processElement. Use that class as the base class for all of your DoFns.

You may need to do the same thing for combiners if your pipeline uses those too.